# What's the alternative to nested stack navigators in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

In my app, I have a main stack navigator that contains all my screens. Some of these screens are part of the login flow, and then once the user authenticates, they go to the main part of the app, which contains a bunch of screens that you can navigate between using a drawer menu.

The way I've implemented this is that in my main stack navigator, I have as navigable components `<Welcome/>`, `<Login/>`, and `<MainStack/>`. In `<MainStack/>` I have a second stack navigator that contains all the screens in the main part of the app, and that stack navigator is wrapped inside a drawer menu. This way, I code the drawer menu only once. So in the primary stack navigator you can navigate between `<Welcome/>`, `<Login/>`, and `<MainStack/>`, and once you're in `<MainStack/>`, you can navigate between a bunch of other screens, all of which share the same drawer menu.

This all works fine, but RN is giving me a warning that I shouldn't include more than one stack navigator in an app; that I should include everything in just one stack navigator. Does anyone know if there's a clean way I can accomplish everything I'm doing here with only one stack navigator?

Thanks!